# Iterate over Map object using JSTL

Tags: jsp, dictionary, jstl, iteration

Is it possible to implement the following using plain JSTL:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<table>
<%
    java.util.Map msgMap = (java.util.Map) request.getAttribute("messageMap");

    for(int loopCount=1;loopCount>0;loopCount++) { 
        if(msgMap.containsKey("/packagesBO/packages["+loopCount+"]/packageId")) {
%>
<tr>
<td><%=msgMap.get("/packagesBO/packages["+loopCount+"]/packageName")%></td>
</tr>
<%
        }

        else {
            break;
        }
    }
%>
</table>
```

Comment: this looks very wrong to me. I think you are misusing the Map. And your loopCount = ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is have a look at c:forEach and c:if and expression language.
Here an example (not tested):

```
<table>
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${messageMap}" varStatus="num">
     <c:if test=${messageMap['/packagesBO/packages["+num.count+"]/packageId']}>
      <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${messageMap['/packagesBO/packages[\"+num.count+\"]/packageId']"}/></td>
      </tr>
     </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```